# How do I set the value of a nested formBuilder group by a html form

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-forms

Example of a nested formBuilder:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.user = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
    quest1: ['', Validators.required],
    account: this.fb.group({
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      confirm: ['', Validators.required]
    })
  });
}
```

And my html form example:

```
    <form class="ui-fluid form-group" [formGroup]="user ">
        <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-6">
               <span class="md-inputfield">
                    <input type="text" pInputText formControlName="name">
                      <label>Name</label>
                </span>
         </div>
         <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-6">
               <span class="md-inputfield">
                    <input type="text" pInputText formControlName="quest1">
                      <label>Question</label>
                </span>
         </div>
         <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-6">
               <span class="md-inputfield">
                    <input type="text" pInputText formControlName="account.email">
                      <label>Email</label>
                </span>
         </div>
         <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-6">
               <span class="md-inputfield">
                    <input type="text" pInputText formControlName="account.confirm">
                      <label>Confirm</label>
                </span>
         </div>
</form>
```

I set my nested controller group as **formControlName="account.confirm"** but it's not getting value from it.
How  can I set nested formcontrol in my form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `formGroupName` i.e,

```
<div formGroupName="account">
```

and subsequently use just the control name within the inner form group

```
<input type="text" pInputText formControlName="confirm">
```

---

Now the inner form will look like:

```
<form class="ui-fluid form-group" [formGroup]="user">
    ... 
    <div formGroupName="account">
       ...
       <input type="text" pInputText formControlName="email">
       ...   
       <input type="text" pInputText formControlName="confirm">

    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: It's working my form is taking data from input but it can not fetch data from data source.

Comment: What is the data source? (You haven't mentioned anything about that in the question)

Comment: It's working with this code email: [(formData.account) ? formData.account.email: null],

Comment: @md.erfan It seems like you are treating reactive forms as template based forms. The idea with reactive forms is separation of concerns. You tie the template to a reactive form and all interactions are done in the component class such as setting values, disabling, validation, listening to changes, etc. Following this pattern will make your life much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need three things,

- formGroup
- formGroupName
- formControlName

In your component.ts:

```
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

userForm: FormGroup;

this.userForm = this.fb.group({
   name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
   quest1: ['', Validators.required],
   account: this.fb.group({
      username: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
   })
});
```

In your Component.html:

```
<form [formGroup]="userForm" class="ui-fluid form-group">

  <div formGroupName="account" class="ui-g-12 ui-md-6">
    <span class="md-inputfield">
      <input type="text" formControlName="username">
        <label>Name</label>
    </span>
  </div>

  <div formGroupName="account" class="ui-g-12 ui-md-6">
    <span class="md-inputfield">
      <input type="text" formControlName="password">
         <label>Name</label>
    </span>
  </div>

</form>
```